# css dropcap - align letter height

Tags: css

I was able to get the drop cap effect, but i want to move the remaining text a little higher. If you see in the fiddle, the text ("apibus ac..") is positioned at the middle of the pink div. I want to move this higher so that it is at the level as the pink div.

https://jsfiddle.net/pmf4s1g4/

**html**

```
<div class="topa-list-widget">
  <h3>My List</h1>
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a href="#">
       Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in aaaa
      </a>
     </li>                                           
    </ul>
   </div>
```

**css**

```
.topa-list-widget ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.topa-list-widget ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.topa-list-widget ul li a:first-letter {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(218, 42, 137, 0.5);
  padding: 0px 5px !important;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vertical-align: top;` is what you want here. From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align), :

> It *[vertical-align: top;]* also applies to ::first-letter and ::first-line.

```
.topa-list-widget ul li a:first-letter {
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(218, 42, 137, 0.5);
  padding: 0px 5px !important;
  margin-right: 1px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmf4s1g4/1/).

EDIT: Apologies, thought you wanted centered. Try `vertical-align: top`. The answer above is edited to match this. If that's not extreme enough, try something calculative, like `vertical-align: -50%;` ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmf4s1g4/2/) of that).

Comment: No it is not. The text was already vertically middle aligned. As I said, I wanted the 'remaining text' to move it higher so it is at the same top level as the pink div. My fiddle & yours look exactly the same,

Comment: @Qwerty Apologies. Try `vertical-align: top`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
.topa-list-widget ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.topa-list-widget ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 20px;
}

.topa-list-widget ul li a:first-letter {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: rgba(218, 42, 137, 0.5);
  padding: 0px 3px !important;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topa-list-widget">
  <h3>My List</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in aaaa
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in aaaa</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in Dapibus ac facilisis in aaaa</a>
                        </li>
                 
                    </ul>
                </div>
```